# Configure virtual hosts in vsftpd

Tags: linux, virtualhost, vsftpd

I've installed and configured vsftpd on my machine. Everything is working ok, i can access it with my ip address but i have some questions.

1. How can i configure virtual hosts in vsftpd? ex, if i have a virtal host called example.com, how can i configure vsftpd to access it with ftp.example.com?
2. Is it even possible? if not, does pureFTPD support this feature?

tks in advance.

Comment: ftp protocol doesn't support virtualhosts at all. It's a http-only thing.

Answer (score 2):

FTP as a protocol has supported a "HOST" command to enable DNS-based virtual hosting for some time. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7151

I know ProFTPD supports virtualhosts, as indicated by their documentation at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Vhost.html.

However, I have not been able to find any documentation regarding vsftpd supporting virtual hosts...